# Текстовое поле поиска по полю для созданного материала "Компания"

Tags: drupal

Не получается отобразить текстовое поле поиска которое я создаю в новом представлении в критерии фильтров.
 В админке для данного представления оно появляется, а на сайте не отображается.
Настройка "Раскрыть этот фильтр для посетителей и позволить его изменять." для текущего фильтра включена. Кеш так же пробовал чистить, но не как не получается включить на сайте.

Answer (score 1):

Попробовать создать представление заново.
Сам недавно столкнулся с тем, что форма фильтра не отображается, только новое создание и помогло.